# How write java batchprocess running from tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, spring, tomcat

I'm writing spring web application that is running on TomCat.7 and one of functionality will be a processing data from db using java.concurrency.

I expect that db processing will be a very time dealing because of calculations, and I need high performance for this process.

My question is if it is good idea (or maybe only possibility) to run that thread in TomCat container?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "run_process", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public RequestWrapper runProcess(ModelMap model) {

        Runnable runCrawler = new Crawler();
        runCrawler.run();
        System.out.println("##run_process!");

        return new RequestWrapper();
    }
```

My project structure is like:

-src 
  -com.scanner.batchprocess
  -com.scanner.crawler
  -com.scanner.webapp.controllers

I don't have any experience in creating programs that are challenging computationally, so I'm afraid that maybe I should create new clean java project with main class that will be called from webapp whenever user run BatchProcess.
Can be a significant time difference in execution time application from Tomcat than True java application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideal choice for you is Spring batch. It has all the features required for batch processing. And its easy to learn, understand and configure. You can make performance tuning in spring batch by introducing threading and other numerous scaling mechanisms refer http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-batch-tutorial/  there are good examples